# Do body customization parts affect performance in any way?

Tags: ps2, need-for-speed-underground-2

There's no indication that they do, but do parts from the body shop such as spoilers and carbon fiber replacements affect the handling of the car? It seems logical that they would.

Comment: Also, there's no tag for nfsu2. Can someone create it for me?

Comment: "need-for-speed-undergroung-2" was too long, so I created "nfs-undergournd-2"

Comment: This does not answer your question but may be interesting as well: AFAIK in NFS Underground (first part) parts of cars that have fallen off impact your car's handling/speed when you drive over them, i.e. parts on the track impact the race and may cost you a win if you don't dodge them.

Answer (score 1):

Body parts do not affect performance.
They are for "Visual Rating" only and are used to unlock DVD cover opportunities as part of sponsor contracts.
Only **Fine-tuning** and a **Dyno Run** will affect performance.

Comment: This is wrong. Body parts will affect handling performance  (front/rear downforce/weight)

Comment: My answer is based in the in-game description. Parts that alter anything in the car inform what was altered. If the information is not in the manual or in the in-game description, that's a functional, implementation and testing error of the game development.

Answer (score 0):

They will alternate handling performance actually. See:

> Performance alterations with spoilers were first introduced in
>   Underground 2, which allowed the player to alter rear downforce
>   settings. Similar implementations were reintroduced in Need for Speed:
>   Pro Street and the Shift series.

Source: https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Spoilers

The root scoops, bumpers, rims, wide body kits and carbon fiber components all have effects. After you change a part and go to dyno run, you can see the handling score changes significantly.

Here is a nice body part tuning guide. I only find a Chinese version: https://www.bilibili.com/read/cv5159860/